# Fake mark a menu item as current_page_item/active in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have a custom post type called Books and a page structure like this:

```
Home
Products & Services
- Services
- Products
-- Books
```

I am using Wordpress custom Menus for the 1st level navigation (displayed horizontally), and wp_list_pages to print out the subnavigation based on the page selected from the 1st level of navigation (the submenu is displayed vertically).

To make things more interesting/worse, I am only displaying Books in the submenu if I am viewing the Products or Books page.

Now, I would like to add the active and current_page_item/current_page_ancestor classes to the Products & Services, Products and Books when I am viewing a single Book (custom post type).

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom class via the [`nav_menu_css_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter, like so:

```
function wpa_65178_nav_class( $classes, $item )
{
    if( is_singular('book') && $item->title == 'Products & Services' )
    {
        $classes[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa_65178_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is to use the built-in walker the Nav Menus use. That would be something like that

```
$custom_walker = new Walker_Nav_Menu();
wp_list_pages( array( 'walker' => $custom_walker ) );
```

Hope that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php conditional to load a jQuery script for when the custom post type is active, and then use jQuery to `addClass` the `current-menu-item` class to the menu items by ID number. Look in your page source to find the menu IDs for each item. These will change if you change the menu; there' no way around that.

```
<?php if ( 'book' == get_post_type()) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1000').addClass('current-menu-item');
}); });

</script>

<?php } ?>
```